# SelectList does not select items when generated inside View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, selectlist

I am having problems to preselect the items when creating SelectList inside View. Here is the Razor code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RoleGroupMappings";
}

<h2>Map roles to groups:</h2>

<table>
    @foreach (var role in Model.Roles)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>@role.RoleName: </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("MapGroupsToRole", "Role", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.Hidden("RoleId", role.RoleId)

                    @Html.DropDownList("Groups", new SelectList(role.Groups, "GroupId", "GroupName", role.Groups.Where(g => g.Mapped).Select(g => g.GroupId)), new { @class = "directory-groups", multiple = "multiple", style = "display: none;" })
                    <input type="button" value="Clear All" class="btn btn-danger clear-selection" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-success save-mappings" />
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Does anybody know what is the problem here?

Comment: I haven't mention that, but GroupId is of type Guid.

Comment: What is the value of `role.Groups.Where(g => g.Mapped).Select(g => g.GroupId)`

Comment: In order to pre-populate mapped groups, I am setting their Mapped property if they are already mapped. So this LINQ query returns all GroupIds (Guids) for already mapped groups.

Comment: So it's returning more than one Guid?

Comment: The `4th parameter` of your Select should be `selectedvalue`. check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Comment: You are right, I should use MultipleSelectList instead. But even then it doesn't work.

Comment: I have a test project here which has your class setup and it's working perfectly.  What's not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to be using a `MultiSelectList` instead of the normal `SelectList`.  Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Groups", new MultiSelectList(role.Groups, "GroupId", "GroupName", role.Groups.Where(g => g.Mapped).Select(g => g.GroupId)), new { @class = "directory-groups", multiple = "multiple", style = "display: none;" })
```

### Update

Being as this is working for me here, I'll show you how I've setup this test project.  Hopefully that will help you to narrow down what the problem is.  Test model setup:

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public bool Mapped { get; set; }
}
```

The view model:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}


public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new TestViewModel
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>
        {
            new Role
            {
                RoleId = 1,
                RoleName = "Test",
                Groups = new List<Group>
                {
                    new Group
                    {
                        GroupId = new Guid("12345678-1234-1234-1234-123412341234"),
                        GroupName = "Group 1",
                        Mapped = false
                    },
                    new Group
                    {
                        GroupId = new Guid("12345678-5678-6789-1234-123412341234"),
                        GroupName = "Group 2",
                        Mapped = true
                    },
                    new Group
                    {
                        GroupId = new Guid("12345678-0000-6789-1234-123412341234"),
                        GroupName = "Group 3",
                        Mapped = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

My view is the same as yours, except with using `MultiSelect` and I also removed `@class = "directory-groups"` and the `display: none;` style.  Both group 2 and group 3 have their `Mapped` property set to true.  This is the result from loading the view:

[image: MultiSelectList]

Comment: If you look at the answer above you will see that everything was ok except I have the same ViewBag variable called Groups that interfere with this in the view. Again, sorry for posting a question without examining controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem in my controller. I was setting the ViewBag.Groups to some values, and obviously it was interfering with my DropDownList which had the same name. Sorry for that, I was staring whole day and I could not find the error, so I become little desperate. I should have looked at my controller, too.

Comment: Generating values in View is a bad idea, the best practice is to send your values from your Controller